# Apache Redirect directive stops working after 400 odd redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

A business partner asked us to implement a list of 1000+ URL redirects from `http://site1.com` to `https://site2.com`. We set up an (old) Apache 2.2 which we cannot upgrade as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1.com
  ServerAlias *.site1.com
  Redirect 301 /url-0001 https://site2.com/...
  Redirect 301 /url-0002 https://site2.com/...
  Redirect 301 /url-0003 https://site2.com/...
  ...
  Redirect 301 /url-1234 https://site2.com/url-...
  RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://site2.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem:**

Any redirect after the first 400+ does not work correctly, i.e., instead of the following redirect:

```
http://site1.com/url-410 --> https://site2.com/foo
```

we get:

```
http://site1.com/url-410 --> https://site2.com/url-410
```

It seems the URI is not being rewritten correctly.

**Question:**
Is there a limit of how many redirect directives one can use in a single vhost or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root Cause:** Redirect #400 looked as follows:

```
Redirect 301 / https://site2.com/
```

All URLs after this one got `404`.

**Solution:** After removing this redirect everything worked as expected.